Shared mailbox in google workplace
I'm new to google workplace, and started to migrate our maildomain to google.
Since we're a non-profit organisation, we got a free limited license.
We want to work efficiently with shared mailboxes (info@, invoice@,...).
How can I create those shared mailboxes and give users privileges to use them?
